# 500 Internal Error Mercado Pago

Tags: c#, mercadopago, pago-in-app

Hola estoy tratando de hacer un pago básico por MercadoPago y me devuelve el "500 Internal Error". Acá les dejo el código que estoy usando. Gracias.

```
var mp = new MercadoPago();
String data = "{" +
     "\"transaction_amount\": 10," +
     "\"token\": \"c2caced385925193f59423f0d630efef14:12 02/10/2017\"," +
     "\"description\": \"Title of what you are paying for\"," +
     "\"installments\": 1," +
      "\"payment_method_id\": \"visa\"," +
      "\"payer\": {" +
      "\"email\": \"test_user_19653727@testuser.com\"" +
   "}" +
 "}";
mp.post("/v1/payments", data);
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste si la respuesta propuesta soluciona el error?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que ese "Json" no tiene el formato tal cual, para solucionarlo:

Instala el paquete Newtonsoft desde Nuget, importas la siguiente clase:     `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;`

Y el código quedaría así:

```
var mp = new MercadoPago();
String data = "{" +
    "\"transaction_amount\": 10," +
    "\"token\": \"c2caced385925193f59423f0d630efef14:12 02/10/2017\"," +
    "\"description\": \"Title of what you are paying for\"," +
    "\"installments\": 1," +
     "\"payment_method_id\": \"visa\"," +
     "\"payer\": {" +
     "\"email\": \"test_user_19653727@testuser.com\"" +
  "}" +
"}";

JObject jsonData= JObject.Parse(data);
mp.post("/v1/payments", jsonData);
```

El contenido del jsonData:

```
{
  "transaction_amount": 10,
  "token": "c2caced385925193f59423f0d630efef14:12 02/10/2017",
  "description": "Title of what you are paying for",
  "installments": 1,
  "payment_method_id": "visa",
  "payer": {
    "email": "test_user_19653727@testuser.com"
  }
}
```